# No matching VM found when running Comma IDE on macOS

Tags: macos, raku, commaide

I installed Comma IDE from [this](https://commaide.com/download) link but when I try to run it by double clicking on the application icon in Finder in the Applications folder I get an error "No matching VM found. Java 1.8 or later is required"

I am on macOS Big Sur 11.2.

NOTE: I tried to install [Java SE Runtime Environment 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html#license-lightbox) and restarted my machine but it did not help.

Comment: Does this happen to run on a machine with the new M1 chip?

Comment: No it is using `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz`

Comment: This is especially odd because the DMG includes a private JVM, and it should be using that.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington I tried now on a different MacBook (Big Sur 11.1) with the new Apple M1 processor. When I click on the Comma CT icon in finder, it first gives a dialog with the message *"To open "Comma CT", you need to install Rosetta. Rosetta enables Intel-based features to run on Apple Silicon Macs."* Then after installing Rosetta and retrying to open Comma I get the same error *"No matching VM found. Java 1.8 or later is required*"

Comment: @HåkonHægland Quoting [from a prior SO answer related to Comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65657337/1077672): "Probably it's worth asking the Comma developers to take a look at it ... Any other information to aid reproduction ... would also be useful." Of particular importance, note who the author of that SO is.

Comment: I think you need the Java SDK, not just the runtime

Comment: try ```$ java -version```, mine says ```No Java runtime present, requesting install.``` and   I can click More Info to get here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html and install this jdk-16_osx-x64_bin.dmg

Comment: now I ran into a new type of error - see new SO here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063622/raku-comma-ide-on-macos-wont-start

Comment: @p6steve Does the answer to the "new SO" also explain this one?

Comment: I have upgraded to Comma 2022.02 (Build #CP-213.5744.3, built on February 28, 2022) - that resolved this issue and now works well. This is managed under File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project SDK > Add Raku SDK > /path-to-your-raku-install/bin/... You have to select the "bin" directory that contains the 'perl6', 'raku' and 'rakudo' commands - on my machine this is ```~/rakudo/rakudo-moar-2021.10-01-macos-arm64-clang/bin/rakudo```. [For the Package Manager setting you need to select the 'zef' command file itself.] Thanks @raiph.